# Interface for Linq-To-Sql Entities

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, entity

This is a pretty straight-forward question. I was wondering if there is some kind of interface I could use to represent any of the entities returned by my Linq-To-Sql dbml?

So I could let's say return things such as IQueryable and it could simply get casted back in its right entity afterward for example?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want to let all entities inherit from the same interface?

Comment: Yes, that would be awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the code generation for your Linq to Sql entities. [Here](http://l2st4.codeplex.com/) you can find T4 templates for Linq to Sql.

If you use those, you can let all entities implement a specific interface.

Or you could implement the interface in another code file on the partial class for each entity.